# How to make JQuery alert only one string from PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery that creates an Ajax call to a PHP script. My PHP script echos 2 strings: check_1 and check_2. The alert() is displaying both the strings in the output. How to get only one string in the output?

PHP:

```
 <?php
 echo "check_1";
 echo "check_2";
 ?>
```

JQuery:

```
$.get("check_ajax.php", function(data) {
alert(data);
});
```

Comment: show us how ur `data` looks like and ul get help :)

Comment: Without having some sort of seperator or knowing exactly what the strings are, you can't! They are ouputted to the page as `check_1check_2`, there's no way to seperate that on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

send the server response as json ... and get it...

try this

**jquery**

```
$.get("check_ajax.php", function(data) {
  alert(data.check_1); //alert the first object "check_1"
  alert(data.check_2);  //alert the second object "check_2"
},'JSON');
```

**php**

```
<?php
  echo json_encode(array("check_1"=>"check_1","check_2"=>"check_2"));
?>
```

Comment: This works! But I have to put all the PHP echos in json_encode() and select what I need in my JQuery. Is there any other solution where all the other PHP echo statements rest at their own place and a specific particular echo could be sent via json? In your above PHP code if I place one more echo statement, nothing comes out.

Comment: you need to create an array and push all the values in it.. and send that array.....like `echo json_encode($result)` where $result is the array of values... without it though you can send it will be quite hard to figure out in your success function

Answer (score 1):

there is couple of ways to do this. one way is string manipulation and removing the text after the new line char of the first string. The other method is actually send your data from php to javascript using `json`. So in your php file you would create a data structure like an array.

```
<?php
   $string = array("check_1", "check_2");
   echo json_encode($string);
?>
```

in the javascript side then you can retrieve the first element from that json array.

```
$.get("check_ajax.php", function(data) {
alert(data[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this : -

```
 <?php
 $html =  "check_1";
 $html1 = "check_2";
 echo $html.'~~~'.$html1;
 ?>
```

JQuery:

```
$.get("check_ajax.php", function(data) {
var res =  data.split('~~~');
alert(res[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem before, but what I do as an alternative solution was to have a conditional statement to separate multiple values returned by php

```
if(your condition here) { 
   echo "check_ 1";
} else { 
  echo "check_ 1";
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
<?php
    $text = array("check_1", "check_2");
    die(json_encode($text));
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$.get("check_ajax.php", function(data) {
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(response[0]); // for "check_1"
    alert(response[1]); // for "check_2"
});
```